# Exchange Access Token does not return output sometime in facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using graph api to exchange access token in one of my application, but sometime its returns blank output.

I am using this code snipet

```
$graph_url      = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .$app_id."&client_secret=" .$app_secret."&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$user_access_token;
            $response       = @file_get_contents($graph_url);
            $response_arr   = explode('&',$response);

            $exchanged_user_access_token = explode('=',$response_arr[0]);
            return $exchanged_user_access_token[1];
```

It will return black response sometime

Any help will appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve this issue. Use the following code

```
<?php
$graph_url      = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .$app_id."&client_secret=" .$app_secret."&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$user_access_token;
$response       = @file_get_contents($graph_url);
parse_str($response,$output);
$extended_access_token = $output['access_token'];
?>
```

I hope that this will help you